# SoapUI REST response session token

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I need to parse a response from the request 1 and pass a specific numeric value from the response to request 2. The below is the JSON response.

---

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 28 Sep 2016 19:42:35 GMT
Content-Length: 61

`{ "response":"New session Created with session Id 123456789101213" }`

---

what should I use - groovy or property transfer? 
if groovy - please let me know what code i should use 
if property transfer - what is the required parsing message i should use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done either ways and that is an additional step.

It is also possible to do without that additional step by using `Script Assertion` for the current test step. There the response can be asserted too.

Pseudo instructions:

- retrieve the response and parse it
- assert if the required value is present in the response
- set the value at test case level
- use the retrieved value using property expansion in other test step of the test case.

**Script Assertion**

```
/**
 * This is a script assertion
 * which reads the response and asserts if there is response
 * reads response property and sets at test case level property SESSION_ID
 */
def jsonString = context.response
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)

//Check if the response is not empty or null
assert json, "Response received is empty or null"
def sessionId = json.response as String

//Check if there is reponse property exists in response json
assert sessionId, "response property is empty or null"
log.info  "Session id : ${sessionId}"

//To set the value at test case level
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('SESSION_ID', sessionId)
```

**How to use the retrieved Session Id in other test steps of the the test case?**

- If the step type is Groovy Script, use one of the below two ways:  `context.expand('${#TestCase#SESSION_ID}')`  or
  `context.testCase.getPropertyValue('SESSION_ID')`
- If the step type is of other types, say SOAP, REST, JDBC, HTTP etc, then use:
  `${#TestCase#SESSION_ID}`

Note: of course, it is also possible to set value at suite or project level too which allows to reuse the retrieved value across the suite or project level respectively